# If $G/N$ is nilpotent and $N\leq Z(G)$, then $G$ is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It seems to me that I didn't need the condition that $N\leq Z(G)$, since I can just prove the theorem by simply applying third isomorphism theorem on a central series of $G/N$.

What am I missing here?

My proof:

Take a central series of $G/N$: $1\unlhd G_0/N \unlhd G_1/N \unlhd ... \unlhd G/N$. Then we have $(G_i/N)/(G_{i-1}/N) \cong G_i/G_{i-1}$ (by third isomorphism theorem) $\cong Z((G/N)/(G_{i-1}/N)) \cong Z(G/G_{i-1})$ (by third isomorphism theorem).

Also $G_i \unlhd G$ by correspondence theorem from $G_i/N \unlhd G/N$.

Comment: So, Your N is any normal subgroup? Is that you are saying?

Comment: yes, $N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Take $ S_{3}$ and take $S_{3}/A_{3} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ which is nilpotent but $S_{3}$  is not!

Comment: I think I got it. I need $N\leq Z(G)$ in order to have a complete central series $1\unlhd N \unlhd G_1 \unlhd ... \unlhd G$.

Comment: @Riju Any subgroup of the center is normal.

Comment: @egreg No, that is not what I said..  He, in his question had asked that $N \leq Z(G)$ is needed for the proof!! So, I clarified that he is claiming that for any normal subgroup the result should hold. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not applying, the lower central series definition? For some positive integer $i$ we have $\gamma_i(G/N)=\bar{1}$, which is equivalent to $\gamma_i(G) \subseteq N$. Since $N$ is central $\gamma_{i+1}(G)=[G,\gamma_i(G)] \subseteq [G.N] \subseteq [G,Z(G)]=1$. So $G$ is nilpotent.

But that was not the question as pointed out by prof. Holt (I was too quick reading you post, sorry!). Well, you argument is right, but you basically constructed a central series down to $N$: $N \leq G_0 \leq G_1 \cdots \leq G$. Now, to stretch to the left for the whole of $G$, the "$1 \leq N$" part must also be a central factor, and this is equivalent to $N \subseteq Z(G)$.

Comment: But the question was not to prove the statement,but to explain why the condition $N \le Z(G)$ is necessary.

Comment: Derek, thanks for pointing out. BTW, I do not understand why there are already 3 votes to close this post... this is NOT a duplicate but merely a question about a sensible proof.

Comment: I haven't voted to close myself, but I think the votes to close are because both the question of why the statement is true and why it is not necessarily true without $N \le Z(G)$ have been asked and answered before!

Comment: Why is $\gamma_i(G/N)=1 $ equivalent to $\gamma_i(G) \subseteq N$

Comment: $\gamma_i(G/N)=\gamma_i(G)N/N$, which can be proved by induction on $i$.

Comment: Thank you! But are they actually equal or isomorphic (which is sufficient here)? I think that $G/N \cong GN/N$ but not equal, or is that wrong? I might very well be wrong...

Comment: No it is really equality here. Note that in your example $GN=G$.